# Using INDEX to only show the prices of a stock using the GoogleFinance function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

The following formula in Google Sheets shows me the closing price of GOOG stock for the last 5 workdays:

```
=INDEX(GoogleFinance("GOOG","close",WORKDAY(TODAY(),-5),TODAY()),,2)
```

However, the result includes the word "Close" as a heading. This is the result in the spreadsheet:

```
Close
1419.85
1442.72
1451.12
1435.96
1431.72
```

The problem is that I ONLY want to display the 5 numbers. I do not want the word "Close" displaying. Is there a way I can modify the INDEX function so it will just display the actual numbers and not the "Close" heading?

Comment: Please let us know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use query along with Index to remove the column header(s):

```
=index(query(GoogleFinance("GOOG","close",WORKDAY(TODAY(),-5),TODAY()),"select * label Col1 '', Col2''"),,2)
```